# Whats the best way to get started on a SonarQube plugin for a new language

Tags: sonarqube

I want to develop a sonarqube plugin for analyzing a new language. The language's grammar is developed. There is a parser available for it. The parser throws out an AST.

I want to write visitors for this AST and then develop rules. Is there a sample plugin(I saw the github sonar-examples but I didnt find it to be clear) or good documentation on what steps I should take? 
Guidance from people who have developed Sonarqube plugins for languages much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This [Supporting New Languages](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Supporting+New+Languages) outline should get you started. Beyond that, go to the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) to ask specific questions.